# Is it possible to deactivate two same paths in Angular Routing (so one is only active at a time)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular-routing

Is it possible to deactivate 2 same Paths with Guards which only redirect in Angular 9? I tried this but the first one is still active when LogoutGuard returns false:

```
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [LogoutGuard] },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [LoginGuard] },
```

In this example LogoutRouter is returning `false` and LoginRouter `true`

So what happens is the following:

```
Router Event: NavigationStart platform-browser.js:88
NavigationStart(id: 1, url: '/') platform-browser.js:79
Object { id: 1, url: "/", navigationTrigger: "imperative", restoredState: null }
platform-browser.js:79
Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode. core.js:40465
Router Event: RoutesRecognized platform-browser.js:88
RoutesRecognized(id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/login', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'login', path:'login') { Route(url:'', path:'') }  } ) platform-browser.js:79
Object { id: 1, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: "/login", state: {…} }
platform-browser.js:79
Router Event: GuardsCheckStart platform-browser.js:88
GuardsCheckStart(id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/login', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'login', path:'login') { Route(url:'', path:'') }  } ) platform-browser.js:79
Object { id: 1, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: "/login", state: {…} }
platform-browser.js:79
Router Event: ChildActivationStart platform-browser.js:88
ChildActivationStart(path: '') platform-browser.js:79
Object { snapshot: {…} }
platform-browser.js:79
Router Event: ActivationStart platform-browser.js:88
ActivationStart(path: 'login') platform-browser.js:79
Object { snapshot: {…} }
platform-browser.js:79
Router Event: GuardsCheckEnd platform-browser.js:88
GuardsCheckEnd(id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/login', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'login', path:'login') { Route(url:'', path:'') }  } , shouldActivate: false) platform-browser.js:79
Object { id: 1, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: "/login", state: {…}, shouldActivate: false }
platform-browser.js:79
Router Event: NavigationCancel platform-browser.js:88
NavigationCancel(id: 1, url: '/') platform-browser.js:79
Object { id: 1, url: "/", reason: "" }
platform-browser.js:79
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Your problem

- You always want to redirect from the url `/`
- If the user is logged in, `/` should redirect to `/home`
- If the user is logged out, `/` should redirect to `/login`

#### Your implementation

You have set up two routes with the same path. Each route has a different `redirectTo` property and `canActivate` guard. You expect that the guard is checked and whichever one returns `true` would then inform the router to redirect to the appropriate `redirectTo` path.

This relies on the Angular router checking specific conditions in a certain order, which is clearly not happening.

#### My solution

Add both guards to a single route.

```js
{ path: '', component: AppComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard, LogoutGuard] },
```

Instead of returning a straight `true` or `false`, the guard will return either `true` or the url to navigate to.

login.guard.ts

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(): boolean | UrlTree {  
    const loggedIn = true; // TODO: implement
    if (loggedIn) {
      return true;
    }

    return this.router.parseUrl('login');
  }
}
```

logout.guard.ts

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LogoutGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(): boolean | UrlTree {    
    const loggedIn = true; // TODO: implement
    if (!loggedIn) {
      return true;
    }

    return this.router.parseUrl('home');
  }
}
```

The natural step from here is to create a base guard that is injected with the authenticated state it should allow through and the url to redirect to.

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jpzgww